# How can I see the evolution of the CPU temperatures in the SpeedFan log file?

Tags: cpu, logging, temperature, speedfan

I run [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.PHP.) in Windows 7 Professional (32-bit) and found some log files in `C:\Program Files\SpeedFan` named `SFLog20110717-0001.csv` through `SFLog20110717-0009.csv`. I opened them, hoping to see a log of temperatures, but all I found was a single column of large numbers as seen below.

How can I see a log of temperatures?

```
Seconds
71822
71825
71828
71831
71834
71837
71840
71843
71846
71849
71852
71856
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here. What is your question? Do you want to know what the log file means? Do you want to create a graph of your system temperature?

Comment: Apparently it wasn’t that unclear. `;-)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The log you have listed shows the time (in seconds). It’s logging to the file every three seconds (though that last one skipped a second, probably because the system was under load at that moment). You have logging enabled, but have not selected any specific values to be logged.

Open SpeedFan and click `Configure` click on each item in the *Temperatures*, *Fans*, and *Voltages* tabs and click the `Logged` button for the ones that you want logged (or clear it if you don’t). Then click the *Log* tab and click the check-box if you want logging, or clear it if you don’t.