# Reading live sensor information through the commandline on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, command-line, monitoring, system-monitoring

I'm looking to be able to read out as much sensor information (thermals, fan speeds, etc.) as possible for scheduled logging on my Windows machine.

I found CPUID's HWMonitor which reads all of the information that I want, but it doesn't seem to have a command-line interface and because I want to be able to automate it, I need a CLI.

I'm not opposed to doing some programming of my own if necessary, but I was hoping to find a tool ready-made for this purpose - if anyone knows of one or a Windows command/protocol that programs like HWMonitor use under the hood, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: [Speedfan](https://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) can generate csv logfiles. See [logging - How can I see the evolution of the CPU temperatures in the SpeedFan log file? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/311632/how-can-i-see-the-evolution-of-the-cpu-temperatures-in-the-speedfan-log-file)

Comment: Thank you! I took a cursory look at it and it looks like I should be able to use it's logging the way I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wmic path Win32_Fan get
wmic path Win32_TemperatureProbe get
wmic path win32_VoltageProbe get
```

Note on my system these are not available because HP didn't make them available.

See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-fan

**Edit**

To get SMART status

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi PATH MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus get /format:List
```

Comment: Thank you! I think for now I'm going to go with the SpeedFan approach, but those do exactly what I asked for so I'm still accepting your answer. :)

Comment: Nice to see they work on someone's computer.

Comment: wmic path Win32_Fan get
No Instance(s) Available.
Yet, HWmonitor sees everything
How do you explore the wmic namespace ? I suspect it's in there but that's not the right name

Answer (score 1):

#### I'm looking to be able to read out as much sensor information (thermals, fan speeds, etc.)

> SpeedFan is a program that monitors voltages, fan speeds and temperatures in computers with hardware monitor chips. SpeedFan can even access S.M.A.R.T. info and show hard disk temperatures.

Source: [SpeedFan - Access temperature sensor in your computer](https://www.almico.com/speedfan.php)

Speedfan can generate csv logfiles (and can also send emails).

> Open SpeedFan and click Configure click on each item in the Temperatures, Fans, and Voltages tabs and click the Logged button for the ones that you want logged (or clear it if you don’t). Then click the Log tab and click the check-box if you want logging, or clear it if you don’t.

Source: [How can I see the evolution of the CPU temperatures in the SpeedFan log file?](https://superuser.com/a/311635/337631), answer by [Synetech](https://superuser.com/users/3279/synetech)

<sup>Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with [Speedfan](https://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.</sup>