# Laptop freezes and only works after a force shutdown

Tags: windows-10, freeze, hardware-failure, lenovo-laptop

I have an year old lenovo thinkpad E480 with windows 10 on it. This problem has started recently. After a jerky movement, the laptop screen freezes completely( at times it goes blank and at times the screen just freezes).  The only way out of this is to forcefully shutdown the computer and start it again. I am suspecting a hardware issue. Probably a faulty connection somewhere. Have searched the web and couldn't find anything about a problem like this.

Thank you.

Comment: Could be anything. Can you run SMART diagnostics on the hard drive? That is a likely failure point on an old system.

Comment: Have used "Crystaldiskinfo", windows default check and western digitals software to check the status and everything says that the drive is good

Comment: Memtest and prime95 are your friends.

Comment: Try speedfan to 1/ check your fan is working and 2/ check your cpu and gpu and other temperatures. Leave it running so you can see the temps at the crash time.

Comment: @spikey_richie - I will try out the ones you mentioned.
David - Thank you for responding. My laptops fan isn't found on the speedfan app. Trying to troubleshoot that at the moment. I am able to capture the temperatures though.

Comment: @DavidPostill - System just crashed after a gentle tap on the back of the laptop. Temperatures of pre-crash aren't captured on speedfan after the reboot. I double checked the "tap on the back" and it worked again. I will just open up the system and check if there is anything that I can find.

Comment: If necessary you can log speedfan data to a file. See https://superuser.com/questions/311632/how-can-i-see-the-evolution-of-the-cpu-temperatures-in-the-speedfan-log-file/311635#311635

Comment: @DavidPostill - Will do. Thank you.